# Separar ou não o frontend do backend?

Tags: php, rest

Estou com uma dúvida que ainda não foi esclarecida, no desenvolvimento com php, o ideal é separar o backend do frontend, usando Rest e consequentemente web services, ou da forma tradicional, rodando tudo no servidor?

Comment: Me parece que há uma confusão entre os termos frontend e view do MVC nessa pergunta. Backend é o código que roda no servidor pra montar a view. Frontend é o código montado que roda no navegador do usuário. APIs sejam elas REST ou SOAP podem ser usadas para interligar sistemas. Sua pergunta é se fazer um webservice para sua frontend ajax ou aplicativo mobile ficar se comunicando é uma tendência. Pode até ser, mas não vejo necessidade dessa divisão extra para a maioria dos casos. Como modismo é uma coisa para dificultar o desenvolvimento, mas já deixa o sistema preparado para quando for evoluir.

Comment: Não tem ideal. Tem que conhecer e aplicar o conhecimento caso a caso. Tem é muita besteira na internet de receita pronta, mas muita delas, senão a maioria, ensinam coisas extremamente complicadas para resolver coisas bem simples, como se todo problema fosse igual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe forma correta.

Embora exista muitos motivos para separar o back end do front end em muitos projetos, há situações específicas (que já passei algumas) que implementar um novo layout nas páginas de capturas foram desperdício de recursos.
Você tem que saber exatamente o que seu projeto precisa.
Se seu projeto é uma plataforma, ou aplicação, e possui páginas institucionais, pode fazer a separação da aplicação do layout, pois a anterior são páginas de capturas.

Se seu projeto, o layout faz parte dos planos de negócios, pode criar todos os módulos separadamente (pesquise por arquitetura MVC), ainda sim fazendo parte do mesmo sistema, como os frameworks e CMSs. No entanto, se usa algum framework, customizar código que não foi escrito por você pode demandar tempo, e tem que vê se vale a pena, muitas vezes, melhor não perder tempo mexendo.

Se está a construir seu sistema do zero, tem a liberdade de estudar um pouquinho de OOP, e criar interfaces escaláveis, com um bom aproveitamento de código voltado para o MVC.

Comment: Certo, um software de grande porte, o idela seria a separação em camadas com MVC, usndo web services somente para consulta de dados estatisticos por exemplo?

Comment: Sim! Como você especificou que tipo de sistema é, nesse caso sim, usar MVC é praticamente obrigatório por questões de manutenção. Lembrando, que MVC, não a única forma trabalhar com a complexidade de um sistema de grande porte. Uma sub-técnica de MVC é o DAO (data access object) que facilita a migração de um uso de banco de dados para outro. Lembrando que sistemas de grande porte devem ser escaláveis, ou seja, resistentes manutenções drásticas. Programação orientada a objetos é altamente requisitada. Quanto mais abstrato, maior  o suporte a complexidade, como uso de SOA, APIs, etc.

Comment: @MarcosPaulo, por que sair negativando todo mundo? Se tem algo melhor para contribuir escreve uma resposta e contribui para a comunidade.

Answer (score 2):

Não há resposta correta ou errada para esta pergunta.

Em minha opinião...

separando você ganha:

- Menos demanda de link de internet e de recursos do servidor.
- Códigos separados e independentes de tecnologia (pode mudar a tecnologia de um sem afetar o outro, exemplo: BACKEND em ASP pode ser mudado para PHP, sem afetar o frontend).
- Pode hospedar o frontend em um servidor e o backend em outro servidor.

separando você perde:

- Performance em máquinas antigas com pouco processador e memória, uma vez que demandará mais processamento do cliente.

Os frameworks mais modernos, exemplo [Angular2](https://angular.io/), utiliza a separação, sendo o frontend em [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) (uma forma simplificada de escrever o [JavaScript](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)) e o backend em [Node.Js](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Comment: Certo, entendi. Mais qual é a forma mais usada tradicionalmente e frameworks para elas você teria está resposta?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.